# Why PopWindow make the screen black for a short time when the Activity finish

Tags: android

```
 private void openInput(View v, String nickname) {
    if (popInputNickName == null) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(UserInfoActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.pop_nickname_modify, null);
        popInputNickName = new InputPopWindow(view, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        popInputNickName.setAnimationStyle(R.style.NewContentAnim);
        popInputNickName.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popInputNickName.setFocusable(true);
        popInputNickName.setTouchable(true);
        popInputNickName.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        edit_nickname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_pop_nickname);
        text_commit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_pop_commit);
        text_cancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_pop_cancel);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nickname)) {
            edit_nickname.setText(nickname);
        }

        text_commit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nickName = edit_nickname.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nickName)) {
                    modifyNickName(nickName);
                } else {
                    ToastUtil.Infotoast(UserInfoActivity.this, getString(R.string.null_nickname));
                }
            }
        });

        text_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popInputNickName.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } else {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nickname)) {
            edit_nickname.setText(nickname);
        }
    }

    popInputNickName.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    popInputNickName.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    edit_nickname.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) edit_nickname.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    openInputTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

[the popwindow show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aErXB.png)

When I enter to an activity(call it A) & shows a popwindow to modify user's nickname. When I finish A, the screen will be black for a while. But when i enter A and not open the popwindow, then no black screen appears, it completes as normal. So i wonder what caused this problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a device specific issue? Try building to a different device and report back.

Comment: I tested my app on emulator_Nexus_5,this problem still happened.

Comment: I am so sorry that the question is not clear. In the end I solved the problem.I used a custom-view that caused this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry that the question is not clear. In the end I solved the problem.I used a custom-view that caused this problem.The edit_nickname in the PopWindow is a custom-view that extends EditText.

```
public class TfEditView extends EditText {

private OnFinishComposingListener mFinishComposingListener;

public TfEditView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TfEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TfEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setOnFinishComposingListener(OnFinishComposingListener listener) {
    this.mFinishComposingListener = listener;
}

@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new MyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs), false);
}


public class MyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

    public MyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean finishComposingText() {
        boolean finishComposing = super.finishComposingText();
        if (mFinishComposingListener != null) {
            mFinishComposingListener.finishComposing();
        }
        return finishComposing;
    }
}


public interface OnFinishComposingListener {
    void finishComposing();
}
```

}

```
private long openInputTime = 0;
private final long canHideTime = 500;
private void openInput(View v, String nickname) {
    if (popInputNickName == null) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(UserInfoActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.pop_nickname_modify, null);
        popInputNickName = new InputPopWindow(view, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        popInputNickName.setAnimationStyle(R.style.NewContentAnim);

        popInputNickName.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popInputNickName.setFocusable(true);
        popInputNickName.setTouchable(true);
        popInputNickName.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        edit_nickname = (TfEditView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_pop_nickname);
        text_commit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_pop_commit);
        text_cancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_pop_cancel);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nickname)) {
            edit_nickname.setText(nickname);
        }
        edit_nickname.setOnFinishComposingListener(new TfEditView.OnFinishComposingListener() {
            @Override
            public void finishComposing() {
                if (popInputNickName != null && popInputNickName.isShowing() && openInputTime != 0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() - openInputTime > canHideTime)) {
                    popInputNickName.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        text_commit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nickName = edit_nickname.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nickName)) {
                    modifyNickName(nickName);
                } else {
                    ToastUtil.Infotoast(UserInfoActivity.this, getString(R.string.null_nickname));
                }
            }
        });

        text_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popInputNickName.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } else {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nickname)) {
            edit_nickname.setText(nickname);
        }
    }

    popInputNickName.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    popInputNickName.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    edit_nickname.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) edit_nickname.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    openInputTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

In the code above ,the popindow can dismissed longer than 500ms from the popwindow begin to show.